# Have QGIS read QML file when opening a project

Tags: qgis, style, qml

Is it possible to have QML files which are read every time I open QGIS? I would like to edit these to reflect changes in the data (in my case I'd just need to change the HEX color codes), but I can't get QGIS to refer to them when opening up. They are in the same folder and with the same name as my TIFF rasters.